# Do invisible creatures provoke opportunity attacks from movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, opportunity-attack, invisibility

If an invisible creature is within 5 feet of an enemy, do they provoke an opportunity attack when moving out of the enemy's reach?

(assuming that the enemy doesn't have some sort of blindsense/tremorsense)